# how to vertically align footer contents with css

Tags: html, css

[image: Footer]

This image can explain my issue. I am trying to get both the copyright text and my Font Awesome icons to be vertically aligned.

Here is my HTML

```
<footer>
<p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Sample SIte</p>
<div id="social">
<a class="social_buttons" href="www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-        linkedin"></i></a>
<a class="social_buttons" href="www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</div>
</footer>
```

And CSS

```
footer
{
max-width:960px;
background-color:#fbfbfb;    
border-radius:10px;  
margin:15px auto 10px auto;
padding: 18px 20px 18px 20px;  
}

#social
{
float:right;
}

.social_buttons
{
color:#575757; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by words "vertically aligned"?

Comment: What exactly i mean is i want the icons on the far right to be level with the text on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
footer{
  background-color: #fbfbfb;    
  padding: 10px;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#social {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Sample SIte</p>
  <div id="social">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Now I am getting somewhere. Using this code, i got the items to align the way i want, but my social media buttons are not "floating" to the right anymore. Can i just fix this by adding a bit of padding or margin to the social media buttons?

Comment: You shouldn't use padding or margin, can you post fiddle of your problem ? `margin-left: auto;` should move your social icons to right

Comment: Sorry, i missed that line. Now it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you don't want to use flexbox there is other way with `display: table` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/173/

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the `social_buttons` class.

```
.social_buttons {
  color: #575757;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: As I know, "vertical-align" is for table cells. So, it will not work in that case.